# Javascript Class properties being initialized as undefined

Tags: javascript, class

I am attempting to create a new object, however one of properties is not being initialized.  `console.log(this.hitboxlen)` outputs `undefined`.  I was encountering the same problem earlier with the hitbox property and resolved it by assigning it outside of the constructor.

This is the main body of code

```
import Position from "./position";
import Character from "./character";

var canvas = document.getElementById("gcanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var char = new Character(10, null, 2);
var hb = [new Position(5, 5), new Position(10, 10)];

char.hitbox = hb;
console.log(char);

function update() {
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(char.hitbox[0].xx, char.hitbox[0].yy, 30, 30);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    char.move("left");
  }
  else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    char.move("right");
  }

});

update();
```

This is the character class

```
import Position from "./position";

class Character {
  constructor(health, hitboxlen) {
    this.hp = health;
    this.hitbox = [];
    this.hitbox = hitboxlen;
  }

  //passed string of either "left" or "right"

  move(direction) {
    var change = 5;
    console.log(this.hitboxlen);
    if (direction == "left") {
      change = -5;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      this.hitbox[i].xx = this.hitbox[i].xx + change;
    }

  }
}

export default Character;
```

Comment: `this.hitbox = [];
    this.hitbox = hitboxlen;` Looks like typo, you meant `this.hitboxlen = hitboxlen`, right? You never assign to a property called `hitboxlen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning this.hitbox with hitboxlen.
The mistake is in the constructor 
**this.hitboxlen = hitboxlen**